# How can i check whether the user is logged in or not after attempting to rate in jquery and display the appropriate message?

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is the script im using to output a message when a person clicks on the stars to rate a content. The problem is, that the message is displayed to both the logged in users and users that are not logged in. I would like to add a different message asking for users to log in (if they are not yet logged in) in order to rate.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#demo2 .stars").click(function ()  {

            $.post('',{rate:$(this).val()},function(d){

            alert('Thanks For Rating');

            });
            $(this).attr("checked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the server side code in php for rating (it is all in the same page):

```
        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['rate']) && !empty($_POST['rate'])) {
            if(isset($session_user_id)){
            $vidid = $vid_result['vid_id'];
            $rate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['rate']);
        // check if user has already rated
            $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `rating` WHERE `rater_id`='" . $session_user_id."' AND `video_id` = '".$vidid."'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                 $sql = "UPDATE rating SET `rate` = '$rate' WHERE `rater_id`='" . $session_user_id . "' AND `video_id` = '".$vidid."'";
                  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {        }
                echo $row['id'];
            } else {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO `rating` (`video_id`, `rater_id`, `rate`) VALUES ('$vidid' ,'$session_user_id', '$rate')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "0";
                }else
                echo "fail";
            }
            }else{
            echo "you have to be logged in to rate";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

The $session_user_id

```
$session_user_id = user_id_from_username($_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: you may check the session in PHP and then process

Comment: Well where do you keep the knowledge of Who this user is and that they are logged in?

Comment: need to check at server and return appropriate response...or more user friendly approach would be change view display depending on login status

Comment: You'll have to do that on the server side. The JavaScript code is not really that relevant to this question. Do you have any PHP code?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have updated my post and included the php

Comment: have you logged or echo'd `$session_user_id` -- Is it actually set?  And, for that matter where is `$session_user_id` set?  Does it look like `$session_user_id = $_SESSION['something'];` ??

Comment: @Zak Yes the $session_user_id -- Is actually set and i have tested it out prior to this. The insert statement will not go through when the user is not logged in however the jquery message still outputs u have successfully rated. (even tho the rating did not really go through).

Answer (score 0):

You are needing to check your callback ... Something like this:

```
$.post('',{rate:$(this).val()},function(d){
    if(d == 'success'){  // In this case it looks like it might be "0" ??
            alert('Thanks For Rating');
    }else{
            alert('Not logged in');
    }
});
```

To start I would use `console.log(d)` to check the actual returned values in both cases.

**EDIT**

put your php into a new file called "rate.php"  -- Pass in video ID with a PHP variable -- and inside rate.php `$_POST['video_id']` should be set

```
$.post( "rate.php",{rate:$(this).val(),  video_id: <?php echo $vidid; ?>}, function( d ) {
    if(d == 'success'){  // In this case it looks like it might be "0" ??
            alert('Thanks For Rating');
    }else{
            alert('Not logged in');
    }
});
```

Comment: hi zak when i do use the console.log(d) i recieve the whole html/php page back as a result. What should i do to to fix this

Comment: Create a separate  page : See my EDIT

Comment: The problem with creating a seperate page is that i couldnt access the video_id which i use to insert the specific rating in.

Comment: hi Zak how can i use the value that has been sent in jquery (video_id) in php, im sorry but im a beginner in regards to this.

Comment: Its still not working and im not getting any error messages either. When i do rate i dont really get any outputs.